# CentOS / RHEL Installers Can't see my Computer's Hard Drives

Tags: centos, rhel, boot, system-installation, hard-disk

I've tried installing Ubuntu and the installation went flawlessly. However, I'm interested in CentOS / RHEL

This is an old Windows Vista era Dell Inspiron 531.

I've seen the info regarding AHCI and Secure Boot, however the most recent BIOS for this machine does not have these options. I've ensured that RAID is turned off and the SATA controllers for both of my drives are enabled.

I've tried the following installers:

- Rocky Linux
- AlmaLinux
- CentOS
- RHEL

During installation attempts, one drive was left unformatted, and one was either formatted by Windows or Ubuntu.

Since I've been able to install Ubuntu just fine, I'd assume there shouldn't be anything keeping me from installing one of these distros, correct? Is there any other option I may be missing?

Comment: It isn’t clear from your post what your question is. It doesn’t seem to match the title.